# Scala and the :: object

Tags: scala

I've been diving into scala, and am absolutely loving it so far. I'm getting around to pattern matching and case classes, and the following has me somewhat stumped. I know what it does, but I want to understand exactly what is happening

```
var list = List(2,3,4)
1::list
```

If I am correct in my understanding so far. Then the :: represents a case object. If so my question is:

how am I "left applying" it to the 1? instead of :: being a method of 1. Basically can someone pull this statement 1::list apart somewhat, showing what is really happening (ie. what methods are being called on what object)

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's annoying that some of the most visible and awesome features of Scala have so much complexity right beneath the surface. So, consider this simple line:

```
val (head :: tail): ::[Int] = 1 :: Nil
```

Each of the three places where `::` appears refers to a different `::`, and a different mechanism in Scala. Let's go through each of them, in order.

### `head :: tail`

What is happening here is *pattern matching*, just like one sees with `case` statements. Pattern matching can appear on `val` assignments, on the left side of `<-` in `for` comprehensions, and on `case` statements.

So, how does this particular pattern matching happens? Well, whenever the pattern is in the format `a b c`, Scala translates this into `b(a, c)`, which is then translated into calls to `unapply` or `unapplySeq` on the object `b`.

So, `::` in `val (head :: tail)` refers to the object `::` (defined through a `case class`).

### `: ::[Int]`

This is a type declaration, so `::[Int]` is a type. `::` itself is a class, and a type constructor as well (because it constructs types given a type parameter -- `::[Int]` is one type, `::[String]` is another type, etc). It is also a subclass of `List`, which has only two subclasses: `::` and the singleton class of `Nil`.

This declaration is superfluous, and, generally speaking, one hardly ever uses `::` as a type or class. I show it here mostly for completeness.

### `1 :: Nil`

Here, `::` is a method. It is a method of `List`, so, since `Nil` is a `List` and `1` is not, it must belong to `Nil` (or be available through implicit conversion).

The mechanism of note here is that methods ending with `:`, when used in infix operator notation, bind to the right instead of to the left. Or, in other words, `a :: b` is equivalent to `b.::(a)`.

This mechanism is rarely used and, I suspect, made mostly to make traditional fp list algorithms more familiar to programmers used to fp. It is used in a few other places on Scala standard library and out of it.

On Scala 2.8, for instance, there's now `+:`, which serves the same purpose of `::`, but is defined for all `Seq`. It is mirrored by `:+`, which appends elements, and whose `:` serves no purpose other than disambiguate it from `+`, which is overloaded to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 10):

An operator name ending in `:` binds to the right. `:: [A]` is really a `case class` and a subclass of `List[A]`, as can be seen in the [Scala API reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/%24colon%24colon.html). `::` is also a method operating on its right argument, a list, taking its left operand as an argument and returning a `::[A]`.

So, in your example, the method `::` is called on `list` with `1` as an argument. This constructs an object of type `:: [Int]` with arguments `1` and `list`.

Comment: @npiv `::` is an operator/method of `List`

Answer (score 7):

The very quick answer. The method :: is being called on list with 1 as the parameter.

Any method name (and yes, :: is a method) that ends in a colon operates on the right operand.

Answer (score 1):

To add some additional information to the other answers:

`::` is both a subclass of `List`

```
final case class ::[B](private var hd: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] { ... }
```

*and* a method on `List`

```
def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] = new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```

which is basically implemented in terms of the first one.

So there is no deep theoretical background behind this one, just keep in mind the rule about methods ending with `:`.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of :: (the "cons" operator) is that it is used in this manner because prepending an element to a list (technically, creating a new list with the new element prepended to the old list) is of O(1) , whereas appending it would be of O(N).  It's an efficiency thing...