# What do all of Scala's symbolic operators mean?

Tags: scala, operators

Scala syntax has a lot of symbols. Since these kinds of names are difficult to find using search engines, a comprehensive list of them would be helpful.

What are all of the symbols in Scala, and what does each of them do?

In particular, I'd like to know about `->`, `||=`, `++=`, `<=`, `_._`, `::`, and `:+=`.

Comment: and the index of Staircase 1st edition, at >> http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/book-index.html#indexanchor

Comment: Related: operator characters vs alphanumeric characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656937/valid-identifier-characters-in-scala

Comment: also, if there are "operators" (which are mostly methods, with a few class names used infix) that you can't find in scalex or the staircase book, e.g. "!!", likely sources are the scaladocs for akka, scalaz and sbt

Comment: example of class name used infix (in German) >> http://raichoo.blogspot.com/2010/06/spass-mit-scala-infixtypen.html

Comment: regarding the issue of filtering by search engines, http://symbolhound.com/ is also a nice alternative

Comment: There are also other symbols like .< when a relational operator acts like a method on an integer, for eg.

Comment: Most of these operators exist so that the developer can pretend to be a Category Theory PhD. For example, `:+=` is append to a mutable collection. Do yourself and your colleagues a favor, and use the English-worded methods whenever possible.

Answer (score 568, accepted):

I divide the operators, for the purpose of teaching, into **four categories**:

- Keywords/reserved symbols
- Automatically imported methods
- Common methods
- Syntactic sugars/composition

It is fortunate, then, that most categories are represented in the question:

```
->    // Automatically imported method
||=   // Syntactic sugar
++=   // Syntactic sugar/composition or common method
<=    // Common method
_._   // Typo, though it's probably based on Keyword/composition
::    // Common method
:+=   // Common method
```

The exact meaning of most of these methods depend on the class that is defining them. For example, `<=` on `Int` means *"less than or equal to"*.  The first one, `->`, I'll give as example below. `::` is probably the method defined on `List` (though it *could* be the object of the same name), and `:+=` is probably the method defined on various `Buffer` classes.

So, let's see them.

### Keywords/reserved symbols

There are some symbols in Scala that are special. Two of them are considered proper keywords, while others are just "reserved". They are:

```
// Keywords
<-  // Used on for-comprehensions, to separate pattern from generator
=>  // Used for function types, function literals and import renaming

// Reserved
( )        // Delimit expressions and parameters
[ ]        // Delimit type parameters
{ }        // Delimit blocks
.          // Method call and path separator
// /* */   // Comments
#          // Used in type notations
:          // Type ascription or context bounds
<: >: <%   // Upper, lower and view bounds
<? <!      // Start token for various XML elements
" """      // Strings
'          // Indicate symbols and characters
@          // Annotations and variable binding on pattern matching
`          // Denote constant or enable arbitrary identifiers
,          // Parameter separator
;          // Statement separator
_*         // vararg expansion
_          // Many different meanings
```

These are all *part of the language*, and, as such, can be found in any text that properly describe the language, such as [Scala Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)(PDF) itself.

The last one, the underscore, deserve a special description, because it is so widely used, and has so many different meanings. Here's a sample:

```
import scala._    // Wild card -- all of Scala is imported
import scala.{ Predef => _, _ } // Exception, everything except Predef
def f[M[_]]       // Higher kinded type parameter
def f(m: M[_])    // Existential type
_ + _             // Anonymous function placeholder parameter
m _               // Eta expansion of method into method value
m(_)              // Partial function application
_ => 5            // Discarded parameter
case _ =>         // Wild card pattern -- matches anything
f(xs: _*)         // Sequence xs is passed as multiple parameters to f(ys: T*)
case Seq(xs @ _*) // Identifier xs is bound to the whole matched sequence
```

I probably forgot some other meaning, though.

### Automatically imported methods

So, if you did not find the symbol you are looking for in the list above, then it must be a method, or part of one. But, often, you'll see some symbol and the documentation for the class will not have that method. When this happens, either you are looking at a composition of one or more methods with something else, or the method has been imported into scope, or is available through an imported implicit conversion.

These *can still be found* on [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html): you just have to know where to look for them. Or, failing that, look at the [index](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#index.index-_) (presently broken on 2.9.1, but available on nightly).

Every Scala code has three automatic imports:

```
// Not necessarily in this order
import _root_.java.lang._      // _root_ denotes an absolute path
import _root_.scala._
import _root_.scala.Predef._
```

The first two only make classes and singleton objects available. The third one contains all implicit conversions and imported methods, since [`Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$) is an object itself.

Looking inside `Predef` quickly show some symbols:

```
class <:<
class =:=
object <%<
object =:=
```

Any other symbol will be made available through an *implicit conversion*. Just look at the methods tagged with `implicit` that receive, as parameter, an object of type that is receiving the method. For example:

```
"a" -> 1  // Look for an implicit from String, AnyRef, Any or type parameter
```

In the above case, `->` is defined in the class [`ArrowAssoc`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$$ArrowAssoc.html) through the method `any2ArrowAssoc` that takes an object of type `A`, where `A` is an unbounded type parameter to the same method.

### Common methods

So, many symbols are simply methods on a class. For instance, if you do

```
List(1, 2) ++ List(3, 4)
```

You'll find the method `++` right on the ScalaDoc for [List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List). However, there's one convention that you must be aware when searching for methods. Methods ending in colon (`:`) bind *to the right* instead of the left. In other words, while the above method call is equivalent to:

```
List(1, 2).++(List(3, 4))
```

If I had, instead `1 :: List(2, 3)`, that would be equivalent to:

```
List(2, 3).::(1)
```

So you need to look at the type found *on the right* when looking for methods ending in colon. Consider, for instance:

```
1 +: List(2, 3) :+ 4
```

The first method (`+:`) binds to the right, and is found on `List`. The second method (`:+`) is just a normal method, and binds to the left -- again, on `List`.

### Syntactic sugars/composition

So, here's a few syntactic sugars that may hide a method:

```
class Example(arr: Array[Int] = Array.fill(5)(0)) {
  def apply(n: Int) = arr(n)
  def update(n: Int, v: Int) = arr(n) = v
  def a = arr(0); def a_=(v: Int) = arr(0) = v
  def b = arr(1); def b_=(v: Int) = arr(1) = v
  def c = arr(2); def c_=(v: Int) = arr(2) = v
  def d = arr(3); def d_=(v: Int) = arr(3) = v
  def e = arr(4); def e_=(v: Int) = arr(4) = v
  def +(v: Int) = new Example(arr map (_ + v))
  def unapply(n: Int) = if (arr.indices contains n) Some(arr(n)) else None
}

val Ex = new Example // or var for the last example
println(Ex(0))  // calls apply(0)
Ex(0) = 2       // calls update(0, 2)
Ex.b = 3        // calls b_=(3)
// This requires Ex to be a "val"
val Ex(c) = 2   // calls unapply(2) and assigns result to c
// This requires Ex to be a "var"
Ex += 1         // substituted for Ex = Ex + 1
```

The last one is interesting, because *any* symbolic method can be combined to form an assignment-like method that way.

And, of course, there's various combinations that can appear in code:

```
(_+_) // An expression, or parameter, that is an anonymous function with
      // two parameters, used exactly where the underscores appear, and
      // which calls the "+" method on the first parameter passing the
      // second parameter as argument.
```

Comment: Did you mean `val c = ex(2)` instead of `val ex(c) = 2`?

Comment: @MikeStay No, I did mean `val ex(c) = 2`.

Comment: => also confers 'call by name' status when used between : and type as in y: => Int'

Comment: => confers return type when used in a function param. def filter ( p:T => Boolean):Array[T] = ..

Comment: `val ex(c) = 2` - this doesn't work. Something change between versions? Shouldn't unapply be in object?

Comment: @prostynick Maybe. I do think I tested this, but who knows what Scala version I was using back in 2011? Clearly it doesn't work now because `ex` is assigned to instead of being used as an object, so I've replaced everything with `Ex`, which works.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral sometimes I see `:::` and `:` operators what are they? reference https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Scala

Comment: @CodeYogi Just methods. Because they end with `:`, the object of which they are methods is on the _right_ side, instead of the left as usual. So `element :: list` is calling `::` on the class of `list`, and passing `element` as a parameter.

Comment: @CodeYogi Ah, with the exception of `:`. A single `:` is _type ascription_. Look that up for more info.

Comment: Maybe one should also mention the :/ and :\ really unintuitive operators. So map.foldLeft( initialVal) is the same as ( initialVal :/ map ) - :\ is foldRight instead.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral You should maybe also add a comment about "this aliasing" with `=>` as it is not covered by your description until now. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246531 or https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html

Answer (score 27):

One (good, IMO) difference between Scala and other languages is that it lets you name your methods with almost any character.

What you enumerate is not "punctuation" but plain and simple methods, and as such their behavior vary from one object to the other (though there are some conventions).

For example, check the [Scaladoc documentation for List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html), and you'll see some of the methods you mentioned here.

Some things to keep in mind:

- Most of the times the `A operator+equal B` combination translates to `A = A operator B`, like in the `||=` or `++=` examples.
- Methods that end in `:` are right associative, this means that `A :: B` is actually `B.::(A)`.

You'll find most answers by browsing the Scala documentation. Keeping a reference here would duplicate efforts, and it would fall behind quickly :)

Answer (score 21):

You can group those first according to some criteria. In this post I will just explain the underscore character and the right-arrow.

`_._` contains a period. A period in Scala always indicates a **method call**. So left of the period you have the receiver, and right of it the message (method name). Now `_` is a **special symbol** in Scala. There are several posts about it, for example [this blog entry](http://blog.yuvimasory.com/2010/06/uses-of-underscore-in-scala.html) all use cases. Here it is an **anonymous function short cut**, that is it a shortcut for a function that takes one argument and invokes the method `_` on it. Now `_` is not a valid method, so most certainly you were seeing `_._1` or something similar, that is, invoking method `_._1` on the function argument. `_1` to `_22` are the methods of tuples which extract a particular element of a tuple. Example:

```
val tup = ("Hallo", 33)
tup._1 // extracts "Hallo"
tup._2 // extracts 33
```

Now lets assume a use case for the function application shortcut. Given a map which maps integers to strings:

```
val coll = Map(1 -> "Eins", 2 -> "Zwei", 3 -> "Drei")
```

Wooop, there is already another occurrence of a strange punctuation. The hyphen and greater-than characters, which resemble a **right-hand arrow**, is an operator which produces a [`Tuple2`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2). So there is no difference in the outcome of writing either `(1, "Eins")` or `1 -> "Eins"`, only that the latter is easier to read, especially in a list of tuples like the map example. The `->` is no magic, it is, like a few other operators, available because you have all *implicit* conversions in object [`scala.Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$) in scope. The conversion which takes place here is

```
implicit def any2ArrowAssoc [A] (x: A): ArrowAssoc[A]
```

Where `ArrowAssoc` has the `->` method which creates the `Tuple2`. Thus `1 -> "Eins"` is actual the call `Predef.any2ArrowAssoc(1).->("Eins")`. Ok. Now back to the original question with the underscore character:

```
// lets create a sequence from the map by returning the
// values in reverse.
coll.map(_._2.reverse) // yields List(sniE, iewZ, ierD)
```

The underscore here shortens the following equivalent code:

```
coll.map(tup => tup._2.reverse)
```

Note that the `map` method of a Map passes in the tuple of key and value to the function argument. Since we are only interested in the values (the strings), we extract them with the `_2` method on the tuple.

Comment: +1 I was having trouble trying to understand the `->` method but your sentence "So there is no difference in the outcome of writing either `(1, "Eins")` or `1 -> "Eins"`" helped me comprehend the syntax and its usage.

Comment: fyi your blog entry link is dead

Answer (score 16):

As an addition to brilliant answers of Daniel and 0__, I have to say that Scala understands [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) analogs for some of the symbols, so instead of

```
for (n <- 1 to 10) n % 2 match {
  case 0 => println("even")
  case 1 => println("odd")
}
```

one may write

```
for (n ← 1 to 10) n % 2 match {
  case 0 ⇒ println("even")
  case 1 ⇒ println("odd")
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Regarding `::` there is another [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311653/scala-and-the-object) entry which covers the `::` case. In short, it is used to construct `Lists` by '**consing**' a head element and a tail list. It is both a [*class*](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon.html) which represents a cons'ed list and which can be used as an extractor, but most commonly it is a *method on* a list. As Pablo Fernandez points out, since it ends in a colon, it is **right associative**, meaning the receiver of the method call is to the right, and the argument to the left of the operator. That way you can elegantly express the consing as *prepending* a new head element to an existing list:

```
val x = 2 :: 3 :: Nil  // same result as List(2, 3)
val y = 1 :: x         // yields List(1, 2, 3)
```

This is equivalent to

```
val x = Nil.::(3).::(2) // successively prepend 3 and 2 to an empty list
val y = x.::(1)         // then prepend 1
```

The use as extractor object is as follows:

```
def extract(l: List[Int]) = l match {
   case Nil          => "empty"
   case head :: Nil  => "exactly one element (" + head + ")"
   case head :: tail => "more than one element"
}

extract(Nil)          // yields "empty"
extract(List(1))      // yields "exactly one element (1)"
extract(List(2, 3))   // yields "more than one element"
```

This looks like an operator here, but it is really just another (more readable) way of writing

```
def extract2(l: List[Int]) = l match {
   case Nil            => "empty"
   case ::(head, Nil)  => "exactly one element (" + head + ")"
   case ::(head, tail) => "more than one element"
}
```

You can read more about extractors in [this post](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112).

Answer (score 9):

`<=` is just like you would "read" it: 'less than or equals'. So it's a mathematical operator, in the list of `<` (is less than?), `>` (is greater than?), `==` (equals?), `!=` (is not equal?), `<=` (is less than or equal?), and `>=` (is greater than or equal?).

This must not be *confused* with `=>` which is kind of a **double right-hand arrow**, used to separate the argument list from the body of a function and to separate the testing condition in pattern matching (a `case` block) from the body executed when a match occurs. You can see example of this in my previous two answers. First, the function use:

```
coll.map(tup => tup._2.reverse)
```

which is already abbreviated as the types are omitted. The follow function would be

```
// function arguments         function body
(tup: Tuple2[Int, String]) => tup._2.reverse
```

and the pattern matching use:

```
def extract2(l: List[Int]) = l match {
   // if l matches Nil    return "empty"
   case Nil            => "empty"
   // etc.
   case ::(head, Nil)  => "exactly one element (" + head + ")"
   // etc.
   case ::(head, tail) => "more than one element"
}
```

Comment: Avoiding this confusion is why I decided to start using the unicode characters for right double arrow (\U21D2), the single right "maps" arrow (\U2192), and the left single "in" arrow (\U2190).  Scala supports this but I was a little skeptical until I tried it for a while.  Just look up how to bind these code points to a convenient key combination on your system.  It was really easy on OS X.

Answer (score 6):

Just adding to the other excellent answers. Scala offers two often criticized symbolic operators, `/:` (`foldLeft`) and `:\` (`foldRight`) operators, the first being right-associative. So the following three statements are the equivalent:

```
( 1 to 100 ).foldLeft( 0, _+_ )
( 1 to 100 )./:( 0 )( _+_ )
( 0 /: ( 1 to 100 ) )( _+_ )
```

As are these three:

```
( 1 to 100 ).foldRight( 0, _+_ )
( 1 to 100 ).:\( 0 )( _+_ )
( ( 1 to 100 ) :\ 0 )( _+_ )
```

Answer (score 5):

I consider a modern IDE to be critical for understanding large scala projects.  Since these operators are also methods, in intellij idea I just control-click or control-b into the definitions.

You can control-click right into a cons operator (::) and end up at the scala javadoc saying "Adds an element at the beginning of this list."  In user-defined operators, this becomes even more critical, since they could be defined in hard-to-find implicits... your IDE knows where the implicit was defined.

Answer (score 3):

Scala inherits most of [Java's arithmetic operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html). This includes bitwise-or `|` (single pipe character), bitwise-and `&`, bitwise-exclusive-or `^`, as well as logical (boolean) or `||` (two pipe characters) and logical-and `&&`. Interestingly, you can use the single character operators on `boolean`, so the java'ish logical operators are totally redundant:

```
true && true   // valid
true & true    // valid as well

3 & 4          // bitwise-and (011 & 100 yields 000)
3 && 4         // not valid
```

As pointed out in another post, calls ending in an equals sign `=`, are resolved (if a method with that name does not exist!) by a reassignment:

```
var x = 3
x += 1         // `+=` is not a method in `int`, Scala makes it `x = x + 1`
```

This 'double-check' makes it possible, to easily exchange a mutable for an immutable collection:

```
val m = collection.mutable.Set("Hallo")   // `m` a val, but holds mutable coll
var i = collection.immutable.Set("Hallo") // `i` is a var, but holds immutable coll

m += "Welt" // destructive call m.+=("Welt")
i += "Welt" // re-assignment i = i + "Welt" (creates a new immutable Set)
```

Comment: P.S. There is a difference between using the single vs. double character operators on booleans—the former is eager (all terms are evaluated), the latter terminates early if the resulting boolean is known: `true | { println( "Icke" ); true }` ⇒ prints! `true || { println( "Icke" ); true }` ⇒ does __not__ print!

Answer (score 1):

Oohoo so you want an exhaustive answer? Here's a fun, hopefully complete, and rather lengthy list for you :)

http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2008/12/scala-operator-cheat-sheet.html

(Disclaimer - the post was written in 2008 so may be a little out of date)

```
!! AbstractActor
!! Actor // Sends msg to this actor and immediately ...
!! Proxy
! Actor // Sends msg to this actor (asynchronous).
! Channel // Sends a message to this Channel.
! OutputChannel // Sends msg to this ...
! Proxy // Sends msg to this ...
!= Any // o != arg0 is the same as !(o == (arg0)).
!= AnyRef
!= Boolean
!= Byte
!= Char
!= Double
!= Float
!= Int
!= Long
!= Short
!? AbstractActor
!? Actor // Sends msg to this actor and awaits reply ...
!? Channel // Sends a message to this Channel and ...
!? Proxy
% BigInt // Remainder of BigInts
% Byte
% Char
% Double
% Float
% Int
% Long
% Short
% Elem // Returns a new element with updated attributes, resolving namespace uris from this element's scope. ...
&&& Parsers.Parser
&& Boolean
&+ NodeBuffer // Append given object to this buffer, returns reference on this NodeBuffer ...
& BigInt // Bitwise and of BigInts
& Boolean
& Byte
& Char
& Enumeration.Set32 // Equivalent to * for bit sets. ...
& Enumeration.Set64 // Equivalent to * for bit sets. ...
& Enumeration.SetXX // Equivalent to * for bit sets. ...
& Int
& Long
& Short
&~ BigInt // Bitwise and-not of BigInts. Returns a BigInt whose value is (this & ~that).
&~ Enumeration.Set32 // Equivalent to - for bit sets. ...
&~ Enumeration.Set64 // Equivalent to - for bit sets. ...
&~ Enumeration.SetXX // Equivalent to - for bit sets. ...
>>> Byte
>>> Char
>>> Int
>>> Long
>>> Short
>> BigInt // (Signed) rightshift of BigInt
>> Byte
>> Char
>> Int
>> Long
>> Short
>> Parsers.Parser // Returns into(fq)
>> Parsers.Parser // Returns into(fq)
> BigDecimal // Greater-than comparison of BigDecimals
> BigInt // Greater-than comparison of BigInts
> Byte
> Char
> Double
> Float
> Int
> Long
> Ordered
> PartiallyOrdered
> Short
>= BigDecimal // Greater-than-or-equals comparison of BigDecimals
>= BigInt // Greater-than-or-equals comparison of BigInts
>= Byte
>= Char
>= Double
>= Float
>= Int
>= Long
>= Ordered
>= PartiallyOrdered
>= Short
<< BigInt // Leftshift of BigInt
<< Byte
<< Char
<< Int
<< Long
<< Short
<< Buffer // Send a message to this scriptable object.
<< BufferProxy // Send a message to this scriptable object.
<< Map // Send a message to this scriptable object.
<< MapProxy // Send a message to this scriptable object.
<< Scriptable // Send a message to this scriptable object.
<< Set // Send a message to this scriptable object.
<< SetProxy // Send a message to this scriptable object.
<< SynchronizedBuffer // Send a message to this scriptable object.
<< SynchronizedMap // Send a message to this scriptable object.
<< SynchronizedSet // Send a message to this scriptable object.
< BigDecimal // Less-than of BigDecimals
< BigInt // Less-than of BigInts
< Byte
< Char
< Double
< Float
< Int
< Long
< Ordered
< PartiallyOrdered
< Short
< OffsetPosition // Compare this position to another, by first comparing their line numbers, ...
< Position // Compare this position to another, by first comparing their line numbers, ...
<= BigDecimal // Less-than-or-equals comparison of BigDecimals
<= BigInt // Less-than-or-equals comparison of BigInts
<= Byte
<= Char
<= Double
<= Float
<= Int
<= Long
<= Ordered
<= PartiallyOrdered
<= Short
<~ Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for sequential composition which keeps only the left result
** Enumeration.SetXX
** Set // Intersect. It computes an intersection with set that. ...
** Set // This method is an alias for intersect. ...
* BigDecimal // Multiplication of BigDecimals
* BigInt // Multiplication of BigInts
* Byte
* Char
* Double
* Float
* Int
* Long
* Short
* Set
* RichString // return n times the current string
* Parsers.Parser // Returns a parser that repeatedly parses what this parser parses, interleaved with the `sep' parser. ...
* Parsers.Parser // Returns a parser that repeatedly parses what this parser parses
* Parsers.Parser // Returns a parser that repeatedly parses what this parser parses, interleaved with the `sep' parser. ...
* Parsers.Parser // Returns a parser that repeatedly parses what this parser parses, interleaved with the `sep' parser.
* Parsers.Parser // Returns a parser that repeatedly parses what this parser parses
++: ArrayBuffer // Prepends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++: Buffer // Prepends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++: BufferProxy // Prepends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++: SynchronizedBuffer // Prepends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++ Array // Returns an array consisting of all elements of this array followed ...
++ Enumeration.SetXX
++ Iterable // Appends two iterable objects.
++ IterableProxy // Appends two iterable objects.
++ Iterator // Returns a new iterator that first yields the elements of this ...
++ List // Appends two list objects.
++ RandomAccessSeq // Appends two iterable objects.
++ RandomAccessSeqProxy // Appends two iterable objects.
++ Seq // Appends two iterable objects.
++ SeqProxy // Appends two iterable objects.
++ IntMap // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++ LongMap // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++ Map // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++ Set // Add all the elements provided by an iterator ...
++ Set // Add all the elements provided by an iterator to the set.
++ SortedMap // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++ SortedSet // Add all the elements provided by an iterator ...
++ Stack // Push all elements provided by the given iterable object onto ...
++ Stack // Push all elements provided by the given iterator object onto ...
++ TreeHashMap
++ TreeHashMap // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++ Collection // Operator shortcut for addAll.
++ Set // Operator shortcut for addAll.
++ ArrayBuffer // Appends two iterable objects.
++ Buffer // Appends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++ Buffer // Appends a number of elements provided by an iterator ...
++ Buffer // Appends two iterable objects.
++ BufferProxy // Appends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++ Map // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++ MapProxy // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++ PriorityQueue
++ Set // Add all the elements provided by an iterator ...
++ SynchronizedBuffer // Appends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++ RichString // Appends two iterable objects.
++ RichStringBuilder // Appends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++ RichStringBuilder // Appends two iterable objects.
++= Map // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++= MapWrapper // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++= ArrayBuffer // Appends a number of elements in an array
++= ArrayBuffer // Appends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++= ArrayStack // Pushes all the provided elements onto the stack.
++= Buffer // Appends a number of elements in an array
++= Buffer // Appends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++= Buffer // Appends a number of elements provided by an iterator
++= BufferProxy // Appends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++= Map // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++= MapProxy // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++= PriorityQueue // Adds all elements provided by an Iterable object ...
++= PriorityQueue // Adds all elements provided by an iterator into the priority queue.
++= PriorityQueueProxy // Adds all elements provided by an Iterable object ...
++= PriorityQueueProxy // Adds all elements provided by an iterator into the priority queue.
++= Queue // Adds all elements provided by an Iterable object ...
++= Queue // Adds all elements provided by an iterator ...
++= QueueProxy // Adds all elements provided by an Iterable object ...
++= QueueProxy // Adds all elements provided by an iterator ...
++= Set // Add all the elements provided by an iterator ...
++= SetProxy // Add all the elements provided by an iterator ...
++= Stack // Pushes all elements provided by an Iterable object ...
++= Stack // Pushes all elements provided by an iterator ...
++= StackProxy // Pushes all elements provided by an Iterable object ...
++= StackProxy // Pushes all elements provided by an iterator ...
++= SynchronizedBuffer // Appends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
++= SynchronizedMap // Add a sequence of key/value pairs to this map.
++= SynchronizedPriorityQueue // Adds all elements provided by an Iterable object ...
++= SynchronizedPriorityQueue // Adds all elements provided by an iterator into the priority queue.
++= SynchronizedQueue // Adds all elements provided by an Iterable object ...
++= SynchronizedQueue // Adds all elements provided by an iterator ...
++= SynchronizedSet // Add all the elements provided by an iterator ...
++= SynchronizedStack // Pushes all elements provided by an Iterable object ...
++= SynchronizedStack // Pushes all elements provided by an iterator ...
++= RichStringBuilder // Appends a number of elements provided by an iterable object ...
+: ArrayBuffer // Prepends a single element to this buffer and return ...
+: Buffer // Prepend a single element to this buffer and return ...
+: BufferProxy // Prepend a single element to this buffer and return ...
+: ListBuffer // Prepends a single element to this buffer. It takes constant ...
+: ObservableBuffer // Prepend a single element to this buffer and return ...
+: SynchronizedBuffer // Prepend a single element to this buffer and return ...
+: RichStringBuilder // Prepend a single element to this buffer and return ...
+: BufferWrapper // Prepend a single element to this buffer and return ...
+: RefBuffer // Prepend a single element to this buffer and return ...
+ BigDecimal // Addition of BigDecimals
+ BigInt // Addition of BigInts
+ Byte
+ Char
+ Double
+ Enumeration.SetXX // Create a new set with an additional element.
+ Float
+ Int
+ List
+ Long
+ Short
+ EmptySet // Create a new set with an additional element.
+ HashSet // Create a new set with an additional element.
+ ListSet.Node // This method creates a new set with an additional element.
+ ListSet // This method creates a new set with an additional element.
+ Map
+ Map // Add a key/value pair to this map.
+ Map // Add two or more key/value pairs to this map.
+ Queue // Creates a new queue with element added at the end ...
+ Queue // Returns a new queue with all all elements provided by ...
+ Set // Add two or more elements to this set.
+ Set // Create a new set with an additional element.
+ Set1 // Create a new set with an additional element.
+ Set2 // Create a new set with an additional element.
+ Set3 // Create a new set with an additional element.
+ Set4 // Create a new set with an additional element.
+ SortedMap // Add a key/value pair to this map.
+ SortedMap // Add two or more key/value pairs to this map.
+ SortedSet // Create a new set with an additional element.
+ Stack // Push all elements provided by the given iterable object onto ...
+ Stack // Push an element on the stack.
+ TreeSet // A new TreeSet with the entry added is returned,
+ Buffer // adds "a" from the collection. Useful for chaining.
+ Collection // adds "a" from the collection. Useful for chaining.
+ Map // Add a key/value pair to this map.
+ Set // adds "a" from the collection. Useful for chaining.
+ Buffer // Append a single element to this buffer and return ...
+ BufferProxy // Append a single element to this buffer and return ...
+ Map // Add a key/value pair to this map.
+ Map // Add two or more key/value pairs to this map.
+ MapProxy // Add a key/value pair to this map.
+ MapProxy // Add two or more key/value pairs to this map.
+ ObservableBuffer // Append a single element to this buffer and return ...
+ PriorityQueue
+ Set // Add a new element to the set.
+ Set // Add two or more elements to this set.
+ SynchronizedBuffer // Append a single element to this buffer and return ...
+ Parsers.Parser // Returns a parser that repeatedly (at least once) parses what this parser parses.
+ Parsers.Parser // Returns a parser that repeatedly (at least once) parses what this parser parses.
+= Collection // adds "a" from the collection.
+= Map // Add a key/value pair to this map.
+= ArrayBuffer // Appends a single element to this buffer and returns ...
+= ArrayStack // Alias for push.
+= BitSet // Sets i-th bit to true. ...
+= Buffer // Append a single element to this buffer.
+= BufferProxy // Append a single element to this buffer.
+= HashSet // Add a new element to the set.
+= ImmutableSetAdaptor // Add a new element to the set.
+= JavaSetAdaptor // Add a new element to the set.
+= LinkedHashSet // Add a new element to the set.
+= ListBuffer // Appends a single element to this buffer. It takes constant ...
+= Map // Add a key/value pair to this map.
+= Map // Add two or more key/value pairs to this map.
+= Map // This method defines syntactic sugar for adding or modifying ...
+= MapProxy // Add a key/value pair to this map.
+= MapProxy // Add two or more key/value pairs to this map.
+= ObservableSet // Add a new element to the set.
+= PriorityQueue // Add two or more elements to this set.
+= PriorityQueue // Inserts a single element into the priority queue.
+= PriorityQueueProxy // Inserts a single element into the priority queue.
+= Queue // Inserts a single element at the end of the queue.
+= QueueProxy // Inserts a single element at the end of the queue.
+= Set // Add a new element to the set.
+= Set // Add two or more elements to this set.
+= SetProxy // Add a new element to the set.
+= Stack // Pushes a single element on top of the stack.
+= StackProxy // Pushes a single element on top of the stack.
+= SynchronizedBuffer // Append a single element to this buffer.
+= SynchronizedMap // Add a key/value pair to this map.
+= SynchronizedMap // Add two or more key/value pairs to this map.
+= SynchronizedPriorityQueue // Inserts a single element into the priority queue.
+= SynchronizedQueue // Inserts a single element at the end of the queue.
+= SynchronizedSet // Add a new element to the set.
+= SynchronizedStack // Pushes a single element on top of the stack.
+= RichStringBuilder // Append a single element to this buffer.
+= Reactions // Add a reaction.
+= RefBuffer // Append a single element to this buffer.
+= CachedFileStorage // adds a node, setting this.dirty to true as a side effect
+= IndexedStorage // adds a node, setting this.dirty to true as a side effect
+= SetStorage // adds a node, setting this.dirty to true as a side effect
-> Map.MapTo
-> Map.MapTo
-- List // Computes the difference between this list and the given list ...
-- Map // Remove a sequence of keys from this map
-- Set // Remove all the elements provided by an iterator ...
-- SortedMap // Remove a sequence of keys from this map
-- MutableIterable // Operator shortcut for removeAll.
-- Set // Operator shortcut for removeAll.
-- Map // Remove a sequence of keys from this map
-- MapProxy // Remove a sequence of keys from this map
-- Set // Remove all the elements provided by an iterator ...
--= Map // Remove a sequence of keys from this map
--= MapProxy // Remove a sequence of keys from this map
--= Set // Remove all the elements provided by an iterator ...
--= SetProxy // Remove all the elements provided by an iterator ...
--= SynchronizedMap // Remove a sequence of keys from this map
--= SynchronizedSet // Remove all the elements provided by an iterator ...
- BigDecimal // Subtraction of BigDecimals
- BigInt // Subtraction of BigInts
- Byte
- Char
- Double
- Enumeration.SetXX // Remove a single element from a set.
- Float
- Int
- List // Computes the difference between this list and the given object ...
- Long
- Short
- EmptyMap // Remove a key from this map
- EmptySet // Remove a single element from a set.
- HashMap // Remove a key from this map
- HashSet // Remove a single element from a set.
- IntMap // Remove a key from this map
- ListMap.Node // Creates a new mapping without the given key. ...
- ListMap // This creates a new mapping without the given key. ...
- ListSet.Node // - can be used to remove a single element from ...
- ListSet // - can be used to remove a single element from ...
- LongMap // Remove a key from this map
- Map // Remove a key from this map
- Map // Remove two or more keys from this map
- Map1 // Remove a key from this map
- Map2 // Remove a key from this map
- Map3 // Remove a key from this map
- Map4 // Remove a key from this map
- Set // Remove a single element from a set.
- Set // Remove two or more elements from this set.
- Set1 // Remove a single element from a set.
- Set2 // Remove a single element from a set.
- Set3 // Remove a single element from a set.
- Set4 // Remove a single element from a set.
- SortedMap // Remove a key from this map
- SortedMap // Remove two or more keys from this map
- TreeHashMap // Remove a key from this map
- TreeMap // Remove a key from this map
- TreeSet // Remove a single element from a set.
- UnbalancedTreeMap.Node // Remove a key from this map
- UnbalancedTreeMap // Remove a key from this map
- Map // Remove a key from this map
- MutableIterable
- Set
- ListBuffer // Removes a single element from the buffer and return ...
- Map // Remove a key from this map
- Map // Remove two or more keys from this map
- MapProxy // Remove a key from this map
- MapProxy // Remove two or more keys from this map
- Set // Remove a new element from the set.
- Set // Remove two or more elements from this set.
-= Buffer // removes "a" from the collection.
-= Collection // removes "a" from the collection.
-= Map // Remove a key from this map, noop if key is not present.
-= BitSet // Clears the i-th bit.
-= Buffer // Removes a single element from this buffer, at its first occurrence. ...
-= HashMap // Remove a key from this map, noop if key is not present.
-= HashSet // Removes a single element from a set.
-= ImmutableMapAdaptor // Remove a key from this map, noop if key is not present.
-= ImmutableSetAdaptor // Removes a single element from a set.
-= JavaMapAdaptor // Remove a key from this map, noop if key is not present.
-= JavaSetAdaptor // Removes a single element from a set.
-= LinkedHashMap // Remove a key from this map, noop if key is not present.
-= LinkedHashSet // Removes a single element from a set.
-= ListBuffer // Remove a single element from this buffer. It takes linear time ...
-= Map // Remove a key from this map, noop if key is not present.
-= Map // Remove two or more keys from this map
-= MapProxy // Remove a key from this map, noop if key is not present.
-= MapProxy // Remove two or more keys from this map
-= ObservableMap // Remove a key from this map, noop if key is not present.
-= ObservableSet // Removes a single element from a set.
-= OpenHashMap // Remove a key from this map, noop if key is not present.
-= Set // Remove two or more elements from this set.
-= Set // Removes a single element from a set.
-= SetProxy // Removes a single element from a set.
-= SynchronizedMap // Remove a key from this map, noop if key is not present.
-= SynchronizedMap // Remove two or more keys from this map
-= SynchronizedSet // Removes a single element from a set.
-= Reactions // Remove the given reaction.
-= CachedFileStorage // removes a tree, setting this.dirty to true as a side effect
-= IndexedStorage // removes a tree, setting this.dirty to true as a side effect
/% BigInt // Returns a pair of two BigInts containing (this / that) and (this % that).
/: Iterable // Similar to foldLeft but can be used as ...
/: IterableProxy // Similar to foldLeft but can be used as ...
/: Iterator // Similar to foldLeft but can be used as ...
/ BigDecimal // Division of BigDecimals
/ BigInt // Division of BigInts
/ Byte
/ Char
/ Double
/ Float
/ Int
/ Long
/ Short
:/: Document
::: List
:: List
:: Document
:\ Iterable // An alias for foldRight. ...
:\ IterableProxy // An alias for foldRight. ...
:\ Iterator // An alias for foldRight. ...
== Any // o == arg0 is the same as o.equals(arg0).
== AnyRef // o == arg0 is the same as if (o eq null) arg0 eq null else o.equals(arg0).
== Boolean
== Byte
== Char
== Double
== Float
== Int
== Long
== Short
? Actor // Receives the next message from this actor's mailbox.
? Channel // Receives the next message from this Channel.
? InputChannel // Receives the next message from this Channel.
? Parsers.Parser // Returns a parser that optionally parses what this parser parses.
? Parsers.Parser // Returns a parser that optionally parses what this parser parses.
\ NodeSeq // Projection function. Similar to XPath, use this \ "foo"
\\ NodeSeq // projection function. Similar to XPath, use this \\ 'foo
^ BigInt // Bitwise exclusive-or of BigInts
^ Boolean
^ Byte
^ Char
^ Int
^ Long
^ Short
^? Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for partial function application
^? Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for partial function application
^^ Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for function application
^^ Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for function application
^^ Parsers.UnitParser // A parser combinator for function application
^^^ Parsers.Parser
| BigInt // Bitwise or of BigInts
| Boolean
| Byte
| Char
| Enumeration.Set32 // Equivalent to ++ for bit sets. Returns a set ...
| Enumeration.Set32 // Equivalent to + for bit sets. Returns a set ...
| Enumeration.Set64 // Equivalent to ++ for bit sets. Returns a set ...
| Enumeration.Set64 // Equivalent to + for bit sets. Returns a set ...
| Enumeration.SetXX // Equivalent to ++ for bit sets. Returns a set ...
| Enumeration.SetXX // Equivalent to + for bit sets. Returns a set ...
| Int
| Long
| Short
| Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for alternative composition
| Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for alternative composition
| Parsers.UnitParser // A parser combinator for alternative composition
|| Boolean
||| Parsers.Parser
||| Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for alternative with longest match composition
||| Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for alternative with longest match composition
||| Parsers.UnitParser // A parser combinator for alternative with longest match composition
~! Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for non-back-tracking sequential composition
~! Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for non-back-tracking sequential composition with a unit-parser
~! Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for non-back-tracking sequential composition
~! Parsers.UnitParser // A parser combinator for non-back-tracking sequential composition with a unit-parser
~! Parsers.UnitParser // A parser combinator for non-back-tracking sequential composition
~> Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for sequential composition which keeps only the right result
~ BigInt // Returns the bitwise complement of this BigNum
~ Parsers.OnceParser // A parser combinator for sequential composition
~ Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for sequential composition
~ Parsers
~ Parsers.OnceParser // A parser combinator for sequential composition with a unit-parser
~ Parsers.OnceParser // A parser combinator for sequential composition
~ Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for sequential composition with a unit-parser
~ Parsers.Parser // A parser combinator for sequential composition
~ Parsers.UnitOnceParser // A parser combinator for sequential composition with a unit-parser
~ Parsers.UnitOnceParser // A parser combinator for sequential composition
~ Parsers.UnitParser // A parser combinator for sequential composition with a unit-parser
~ Parsers.UnitParser // A parser combinator for sequential composition
unary_! Boolean
unary_+ Byte
unary_+ Char
unary_+ Double
unary_+ Float
unary_+ Int
unary_+ Long
unary_+ Short
unary_- BigDecimal // Returns a BigDecimal whose value is the negation of this BigDecimal
unary_- BigInt // Returns a BigInt whose value is the negation of this BigInt
unary_- Byte
unary_- Char
unary_- Double
unary_- Float
unary_- Int
unary_- Long
unary_- Short
unary_~ Byte
unary_~ Char
unary_~ Int
unary_~ Long
unary_~ Short
```

Answer (score 0):

There are good exhaustive answers here.

One key point for me is there are 2 categories of these

The symbols that the op has mentioned are function names in the scala sdk. In scala it is legal to write functions having names with these characters including unicode ones. It will be a good long list to try and mention all of them from the sdk that are already mentioned in the other answers

Then there are symbols that are not function names but part of the language syntax itself such as `=>`, `_` or operators such as `&&`, `||` , etc.