# In Scala, what exactly does 'val a: A = _' (underscore) mean?

Tags: scala, initialization

What exactly does `val a: A = _` initialize a value to? Is this a typed null? Thanks.

Comment: Scala's [symbol soup](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7890032).

Answer (score 160, accepted):

`val a: A = _` is a compile error. For example:

```
scala> val a: String = _
<console>:1: error: unbound placeholder parameter
       val a: String = _
                       ^
```

What does work is `var a: A = _` (note `var` instead of `val`). As Chuck says in his answer, this initialises the variable to a default value. From the Scala Language Specification:

> 0 if T is Int or one of its subrange types,
>   0L if T is Long,
>   0.0f if T is Float,
>   0.0d if T is Double,
>   false if T is Boolean,
>   () if T is Unit,
>   null for all other types T.

Comment: Ha, nice catch on the val/var switch. My brain just skimmed right past it.

Comment: Any insight into why this hasn't been made to work with `val`?

Comment: @ErikAllik: This is pure speculation, but `val a: Int = _` is probably a compilation error because it would be bad practice if it worked.

It would just be an obfuscated way of writing `val a: Int = 0`. Setting a `var` to a default value makes sense since a `var` is expected to change, but a `val` is fixed so best practice would be to assign a value explicitly.

Comment: @Shuklaswag: Only if you know its an integer. I'm trying to use this to initialise a val of a type that I don't know yet.

Answer (score 34):

It initializes `a` to the default value of the type `A`. For example, the default value of an Int is 0 and the default value of a reference type is null.

Comment: What is the default value of a class that mixes in the `NotNull` trait? :-)

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet: As of Scala 2.9.0.1 (which is the most recent version I've used), the default value of a class that mixes in the NotNull trait is — dramatic pause — **null**. I expect this will probably change at some point, but currently it seems `_` trumps `NotNull`.