# Is it possible to declare an object and initialize it later in Scala

Tags: scala

Just started on unit testing using Scala and had this basic question.

```
class Test {
  ClassToBeTested testObject;

  @Before
  void initializeConstructor() {
    testObject = new ClassToBeTested(//Blah parameters);
  }

  @Test
  //Blah
}
```

The above example in Java shows that I can just declare an object of type `ClassToBeTested` and initialize it later. Can this be done in Scala? I tried it

```
class Test {
  var testObject = new ClassToBeTested()

  @Before def initializeConstructor() {
    //I do not know how to proceed here!!!!!!
  }

  @Test def testOne() {
    //Some test
  }
}
```

I don't want to do everything inside the `testOne()` because I want to use the object in different tests. The parameters of the constructor are mocks and in `JUnit` I know that mocks are not initialized if I initialize an object globally and not inside `@Before`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you can make it:

```
class Test {
  var testObject: ClassToBeTested = _

  @Before 
  def initializeConstructor() {
    testObject = new ClassToBeTested()
  }

  @Test 
  def testOne() {
    //Some test
  }
}
```

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336640/in-scala-what-exactly-does-val-a-a-underscore-mean) on underscore init.

---

You can also read more about this in Section [18.2 Reassignable variables and properties](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/stateful-objects.html#18.2) of Programming in Scala book. Here is quote, that can be helpful to you:

> More precisely, an initializer "= _" of a field assigns a zero value to that field. The zero value depends on the field's type. It is 0 for numeric types, false for booleans, and null for reference types. This is the same as if the same variable was defined in Java without an initializer.
>
> Note that you cannot simply leave off the "= _" initializer in Scala. If you had written:
>
> ```
>  var celsius: Float
> ```
>
> this would declare an abstract variable, not an uninitialized one

Comment: I thougth scala cannot infer type when you initialize variable to default value by placing underscore.

Comment: Thanks!! So can this be used for normal variables also? Say, `var temp = _` and use this variable anywhere inside the class?

Comment: @noMAD see my update. You can use it only for the class members, but not for the local variables - they should be always initialized.