# How to initialize a field by calling a method

Tags: scala, class

The following class refuses to compile:

```
class InitTest { // Class 'InitTest' must either be declared abstract
                 // or implement abstract member 'v: Int'

  var v: Int

  def int(v : Int) = {
    this.v = v 
  }
}
```

I was kind of surprise by that we can't just leave values "uninitialized". In Java, it would be assigned with `null`. In Scala, it does not compile. How to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class InitTest {
  var v: Int = _
  def int(v : Int) = {
    this.v = v 
  }
}
```

Since `v` has a value type, there is no way of assigning `null` to it. However, Scala lets you use `_` to represent the "zeroed" value. For numbers, that is zero and for pointers that is null. Good way of representing uninitialized values.

Comment: But what does it mean to assign `_`?

Comment: @stella See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336640/in-scala-what-exactly-does-val-a-a-underscore-mean