# Scala: Declare a variable for holding a function (lambda) without immediate assignment

Tags: scala

I want to declare a `var` that can hold a function, but I want to assign the function only later.

How do I declare such a var, e.g. when it takes no parameters and returns nothing?

I tried this but that's not accepted:

```
private var myFunction : ()
```

Later in the code, I'd assign code to it like this, I imagine:

```
myFunction = () => { doSomething() }
```

Comment: Don't do that. Vars are a wrong solution to any problem 99% of the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so:

```
  def doSomething(): Unit = ???

  class A {
    private var m1: Function0[Unit] = _

    // later down the line
    m1 = () => { doSomething() }

    private var m2: () => Unit = _

    // later down the line
    m2 = () => { doSomething() }
  }
```

Just declare the type of the function using function literal syntax, or with one of the `FunctionN` traits.

## Edit

Your mistake was declaring `myFunction` with invalid syntax.

Syntax is `[visibility] {var|val|lazy val} {variable-name}[:<variable-type>}[=<value]`

Where `[]` denotes optional parts and `{}` mandatory parts.

Visibility is assumed `public` if you omit it. As to the underscore you can check its meaning [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336640/in-scala-what-exactly-does-val-a-a-underscore-mean)

Comment: Ah, so my mistake was that I didn't understand that I have to assign _something_ to the var. And "_" is the best solution, I assume? (I only am trying to fix some Scala code someone else has written, I'm not planning to learn the compile language to write my own apps in it. Most of it is pretty easy to understand when knowing other langs, such as Swift, anyway).

Comment: My main problem was apparently to figure out what the "variable-type" for a function signature with no return value is.