# Questions about scala

Tags: scala

I am currently learning scala. I am reading Scala for the impatient.

1.)

**Guards**

Is there a difference?

```
for (i <- 0 to 10)if (i % 2 == 0) println(i)

for (i <- 0 to 10 if i % 2 == 0) println(i)
```

2.)

I always see the following symbol `=>` but they never explain what it does.

Sometimes I think it is a cast but then it is something completely different, I hope you can clear things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.) Yes, there is a difference, the first if a normal `if` statement inside of the closure you pass to the for-comprehension. The second is an actual guard. It will actually call `withFilter` on the range, before calling `foreach`. So the translation of the two things will look like this:

```
0.to(10).foreach(i => if(i % 2 == 0) println(i) )
0.to(10).withFilter(x => x % 2 == 0).foreach(i => println(i))
```

To add a little more context, calling `withFilter` or even just `filter` instead of using a normal if statement has some benefits. In a for comprehension, you can have nested calls to map, flatmap, filter, collect etc. so if you add guards, you can prevent a lot af calls from actually happening. For example:

```
for {
  x <- 0 until 10
  y <- 10 until 20
} {
  if(x % 2 == 0) println(x*y)
}
```

would call the actual closure 100 times

```
for {
  x <- 0 until 10
  if x % 2 == 0
  y <- 10 until 20
} println(x*y)
```

this will only call it 50 times, while the result stays the same.

2.)

`=>` separates the argument list of a function/closure from the body.

This `case e: NumberFormatException => None` is a part of a partial function. Here the `=>` separates the "argument" `e` from the body `None`.

In a type signature like in `someFunction(i: (A) => Int)` it implies that `i` is of the type `Function1[A,Int]`, read "function from `A` to `Int`".

Comment: Okay thank you. But could you explain the second part a little bit more? Some examples would be `def someFunction(i: (A) => Int)` or `case e: NumberFormatException => None` Both seem completely different to me.

Comment: @MaikKlein IMHO, the two cases you mention *are* completely different. drexin's explanation is pretty good, though. Now, please not that many symbols in Scala have *many* different meanings. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7890032/53013) for an overview, though, sadly, `=>` was not well covered there.