# Use of ' -> ' and ' <- ' operators in scala

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala Punctuation (aka symbols, operators)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888944/scala-punctuation-aka-symbols-operators)

What is the purpose of `->` and `<-` operators in scala? And is there any useful document that explaing the various operators used in scala - I seem to to be getting confused too much, too often :)

Comment: To search for Scala symbols such as "->" in Stack Overflow, you can use http://symbolhound.com/.

To search Scala documentation, you can use http://scalex.org/.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two operators are very different.

The `->` operator is used to make a `Tuple2`.

```
scala> 1 -> 2
res0: (Int, Int) = (1,2)
```

The `<-` is used in for-statements to mean something like "in".  So the following means, for each `x` in `someList`, print `x`:

```
for(x <- someList) println(x)
```

Comment: Is it just me or is Scala weirdly designed, why would you use symbols instead of a basic "for x in someList" format, which is used by all popular programming languages. I have noticed many other weird notations in Scala that break from the traditional way of writing code and provide no additional benefit.