# what this scala symbol ->_ means

Tags: scala

can someone assist me understanding this code

```
case "Foo" Foo(data) -> _ => { /*.. implementation */}
```

I see the usage of Foo.unapply(data) 
but I don't understand what this part

> -> _

how and when to use it

Comment: There is a popular question that also cover your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888944/scala-punctuation-aka-symbols-and-operators

Comment: btw you can easily understand this code if you use intellij http://gyazo.com/dcf31d20ccb925bed0e302fd45df7710.png or if you process it with scala x-ray http://scastie.org/2026

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks like someone is being *way* too clever for their own good. Suppose I've got the following:

```
case class Foo[A](command: String, data: A)

object -> { def unapply[A, B](p: (A, B)) = Some(p) }
```

Now I can write this:

```
scala> Foo("foo", (42, 'whatever)) match {
     |   case "foo" Foo(data) -> _ => data
     | }
res0: Int = 42
```

Thanks to the magic of Scala's infix patterns, this is equivalent to the following:

```
Foo("foo", (42, 'whatever)) match {
  case Foo("foo", data -> _) => data
}
```

Except that the infix version is guaranteed to confuse and annoy your code's future readers.

Comment: +1 because you understood the case right away. And for the scala magic

Comment: Wow.  I didn't know that the compiler could perform _that_ transform--moving the `-> _` inside the parens, essentially?  Or is that not what's going on?

Comment: @RexKerr: The parentheses aren't actually doing any work here—you could just as well (i.e., horribly) write `case "foo" Foo data -> _`.

Comment: Oh, oh, of course.  It is _so_ tempting to interpret `Foo(...)` as the highest precedence instead of parens as a useless wrapper around `data`.

Comment: That is definitely a Scala puzzler!

Comment: Can you please link in the reference on how it converts `"foo" Foo(data) -> _` to `Foo("foo", data -> _)`. I have seen this with `=:=` also where `=:=[A,B]` is same as `A =:= B`. I do not know by what to search in reference for this

Comment: unconventional use of parentheses may be confusing, but otherwise it's definitely not a puzzler, e.g. something like case a :: b :: Nil => is something you encounter on the first day of scala

Comment: @OlegYch: A puzzler's no fun if it doesn't take more or less everyday ingredients and turn them into something ghastly. This definitely fits the bill.

Comment: @Jatin: Look up 8.1.10 ("Infix Operation Patterns") in the Scala reference.

Comment: @TravisBrown thanks , one question - why data yields the 42 and not the "whatever" ?

Comment: @igx: `data -> _` is desugared to `->(data, _)`, and when we match `(42, 'whatever)` against that, we end up with `data` having the value `42`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Thanks ! that certainty clarify this issue