# Where to search for Scala syntax - reserved words, keywords, operators?

Tags: scala, operators

It seems Google is not a good place to search Scala syntax. Are there any good places for that, e.g., reserved words like `<:`? Thanks

Comment: There is http://symbolhound.com/ but it seems to be broken right now. It doesn't show search results to me.

Comment: Good question. Searching for the meaning of some weird operators can be really cumbersome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. A good starting point may be the [Finding symbols FAQ](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html) at scala-lang.org. Common operators  used in standard classes be found in this [operator cheat sheet](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.cz/2008/12/scala-operator-cheat-sheet.html) (although the cheat sheet doesn't include symbols like `<:`).
2. You can also try [Scala reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf). It is a PDF that you can fulltext-search for strings like `<:`, although the reference documentation is a bit complex.
3. Then there are are some interesting question here on SO, e.g., [Scala punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7888944/2032064), or [all uses of underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8000903/2032064).
4. [Symbolhound.com](http://symbolhound.com/) is a search engine that doesn't ignore special characters. It can point you in the right direction, often here to Stack Overflow.
5. Finally, Scala translates some symbols in method names to be compatible with JVM, e.g., `++:` gets translated to `$plus$plus$colon` (see translation table [here](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala)). You could search google for, e.g., [`site:scala-lang.org $colon$colon`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:scala-lang.org+%22%24colon%24colon%22). this seems to locate only object/class names, though.

PS: I also checked if you really can't ask Google: seems you [can't](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/49) :(

Comment: Yep, good point, it wasn't working at the time I wrote the answer.