# What is the use of ::: (triple colons) in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to scala..I came across a concept where it says like below:

```
{ val x = a; b.:::(x) }
```

> In this block a is still evaluated before b, and then the result of
>   this evaluation is passed as an operand to b’s ::: method

What is the meaning of above  statement..
I tried like below:

var a =10
var b =20
What should be the result i should expect.
Can somebody please give me an example...

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `:::` operator is defined on [`List` trait](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) and concatenates two lists. Using it on `Int` like in your example (`var a=10`) shouldn't work (unless you define such operator yourself).

Here is how it works on lists:

```
val a = List(1, 2);
val b = List(3, 4);
val c1 = a ::: b  // List(1, 2, 3, 4) 
val c2 = a.:::(b) // List(3, 4, 1, 2)
```

Calling `:::` with the infix syntax (`c1`) and method call syntax (`c2`) differ in the order in which lists are concatenated (see Jörg's comment).

The statement "a is still evaluated before b" means that `a` is evaluated before passing it as an argument to the method call. Unless the method uses  [call by name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13337338/2032064), its arguments are evaluated before the call just like in Java.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32036188/2032064) could give you some hint how to search for meaning of Scala operators and keywords.

Comment: Thanks @Mifeet..Just had one question...Does it only support List and trait...Nice explanation....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, but AFAIK `:::` is available only on objects inheriting from `List`. For other collections you can use [++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6560117/2032064).

Comment: "Calling `:::` as with the infix syntax (`c1`) and method call syntax (`c2`) are equivalent." – No, they are not. Methods whose names end with `:` are right-associative when called with infix syntax, i.e. `a ::: b` is equivalent to `b.:::(a)`, not `a.:::(b)` and evaluates to `List(3, 4, 1, 2)`, not `List(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: This answer is just wrong; the code clearly does not produce the outputs shown.  As Jörg points out, `c1` and `c2` are not equivalent or even "almost equivalent", they are literally opposites.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, seems that I forgot to update the answer properly.