# What does the arrow in an import statement do?

Tags: scala

I've found the the following `import` in some `scala`:

```
import Predef.{println => _, _}
```

What does the `=>` do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala punctuation (AKA symbols and operators)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888944/scala-punctuation-aka-symbols-and-operators)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally `=>` in an `import` allows you to alias an existing name into an alternate name:

```
import scala.{Int => i32}
```

This would allow you to use `i32` in place of `Int`

Further, importing `_` imports all symbols into the current namespaces.

Now, aliasing a name into `_`, however does the opposite, i.e. excludes it from the import:

```
import Predef.{println => _, _}
```

means

> *Import all from `Predef` except `println`

Comment: And why I can import only methods from `object` and not a `class`?

Comment: You import the class, which you then have to make an instance of, and *then* you can use the methods on it.  That's how classes work.

Comment: You can import methods from the *instance* of a `class`, but until a `class` has been instantiated, the methods really only exist as a recipe. An `object` acts basically like a singleton instantiation of some hidden `class`, hence you can import methods from it

Comment: Correct. Think of `object` imports as Java's static method imports and class instance imports are identical in behavior between *scala* and Java