# Scala what is <:< operator

Tags: scala

There is some explanation [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html)

> Types and objects can also have symbolic names; in particular, it should be
>       mentioned that for types with two type parameters the name can be written 
>       between parameters, so that e.g. `Int <:< Any` is the same as `<:<[Int, Any]`.

But, i still couldn't quite get it. I'd appreciate if someone can provide an explanation with an example.

Comment: For starters, it's a type, not an operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala punctuation (AKA symbols and operators)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888944/scala-punctuation-aka-symbols-and-operators)

Comment: That post does not talk about `<:<`

Comment: A scala reddit article just came out that discusses this operator - http://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html.

Comment: checkout this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/what-do-and-mean-in-scala-2-8-and-where-are-they-documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a class defined in object `Predef`:

```
abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends Function1[From, To]
```

> An instance of `A <:< B` witnesses that `A` is a subtype of `B`.

That the class name is symbolic has no particular consequences, it could have been named `IsSubType[From, To]` aka `From IsSubType To`.

You get 'evidence' instances of this class by way of `Predef.$conforms`:

```
implicit def $conforms[A]: <:<[A, A]
```

The use case of this is where you have a type `A` but you want to operate on sub-type `B <: A`. Then you can simply ask for this implicit evidence:

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def x: A

  // def fails: Int = x * x -- not possible, we don't know that A is an Int

  def succeeds(implicit ev: A <:< Int): Int = x * x
}
```

From the use-site, the compiler only allows us to call `succeeds` if `A <: Int`, since otherwise we wouldn't be able to get the `ev` parameter. The implicit look-up works because of how the compiler can infer the upper bounds of the sought type based on the variance of the type parameters `From` and `To` of `<:<`.

(Of course `Int` is a final type, so we could have also asked for equality `A =:= Int`, this is just to have a simple example.)