# What does # mean in scala

Tags: scala

When I read Spark source Code, I see a code snippet

```
def in[U <: Universe with Singleton](otherMirror: scala.reflect.api.Mirror[U]): U # WeakTypeTag[T]
```

what does # mean here, and where can I find the doc of the scala symbol eg "<:<" , "<%<", "#" and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question might have been asked and answered here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7890032/9938789

Hope that helps!

Hope the moderator doesn't delete this answer before checking it out please! ;p

Comment: I don't find answer in your url, but I have found it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443004/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-scala