# What's the meaning of -> in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

When I read the book 《Functional Programming in scala》.
I find the expression like this:

```
case (Cons(h, t), Empty) => 
    Some(f(Some(h()), Option.empty[B]) -> (t(), empty[B]))
```

What's the difference between

```
Some(f(Some(h()), Option.empty[B]), (t(), empty[B]))
```

Comment: (1 -> 2), (1, 2) is the same type (Int, Int) = (1,2), so it's just for look bueatifully?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888944/what-do-all-of-scalas-symbolic-operators-mean.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I understand this! The ArrowAssoc is the implicit class and 1 -> 2 actually is Predef.ArrowAssoc(1).->(2) and it returns the result (1, 2). It's just for analysis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 2nd example compiles, it should compile with a warning: `creating a 2-tuple: this may not be what you want` Otherwise it would fail because `Some()` doesn't take two parameters. The 1st example should compile because the `->` is explicitly creating the tuple to send as a single parameter to the (outer) `Some()`.

When creating a tuple of two elements you have the option of using parentheses and comma `(5, true)`, or the arrow `5 -> true`. In most situations the parentheses are optional when using the arrow version.

The arrow can't be used if you want more than 2 elements (i.e. **not** nested tuples):

```
'c' -> 'b' -> 'x'
//res0: ((Char, Char), Char) = ((c,b),x)
```

Comment: It will compile, actually, as the compiler translates `Some(1, 2)` into `Some((1, 2))`, absent the [`-Yno-adapted-args`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html) compiler flag.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon; Hmm, you're right about `Some(1,2)` but my REPL session threw an error with the original example code. Answer adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Interesting, I don't even get a warning in the Scala 2.12.4 repl. Of course, I can't compile the OP's code as is because some definitions are missing.

Answer (score 0):

The `->` is actually a method of the ArrowAssoc class to which every object can be implicitly converted. See the object `scala.Predef`. It is defined as:

`def -> [B](y: B): Tuple2[A, B] = Tuple2(x, y)`

This means that `1 -> 2` is equivalent to `1.->(2)` which evaluates to `Tuple2(1, 2)`. This is also explained in section 21.4 of the book (3rd edition).